# Tabla de Bootstrap no se adapta a distintas resoluciones

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en Bootstrap la cual no se adapta bien en distintas resoluciones...sobretodo en la sm y xs

Le di a cada columna de la tabla unas columnas de medidas para que el contenido no cambiara el diseño de la tabla, pero no se adapta bien conforme cambio la resolución

```
<table id="productSizes" class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <th class="col-2">Producto</th>
      <th class="col-2">Imagen</th>
      <th class="des-xs col-6">Descripción</th>
      <th class="col-1">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="col-1">Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-2 title-producto">PRODUCTO NUMERO UNO</td>
      <td class="col-2"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/2019/images/pruebaproducto.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td class="col-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, natus. Dolore architecto iste tempore eveniet voluptatem voluptatum perferendis sunt ex, itaque saepe. Quidem assumenda a aperiam aut sapiente laborum voluptatum.</td>
      <td class="col-1">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>7</option>
              <option>8</option>
              <option>9</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>11</option>
              <option>12</option>
              <option>13</option>
              <option>14</option>
              <option>15</option>
              <option>16</option>
              <option>17</option>
              <option>18</option>
              <option>19</option>
              <option>20</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1 td-precio">60€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-2 title-producto">PRODUCTO NUMERO DOS</td>
      <td class="col-2"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/2019/images/pruebaproducto.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td class="cdol-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio facilis harum tempore id dolor, exercitationem amet eius unde, asperiores at consequuntur, cum fugiat esse doloremque molestias ipsa officia ipsum repellendus. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo corporis cupiditate repellendus porro, maiores minus, molestiae omnis corrupti error ullam perferendis laudantium, ratione quidem necessitatibus est. Alias iste tempora doloribus.</td>
      <td class="col-1">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>7</option>
              <option>8</option>
              <option>9</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>11</option>
              <option>12</option>
              <option>13</option>
              <option>14</option>
              <option>15</option>
              <option>16</option>
              <option>17</option>
              <option>18</option>
              <option>19</option>
              <option>20</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1 td-precio">60€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-2 title-producto">PRODUCTO NUMERO TRES</td>
      <td class="col-2"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost/2019/images/pruebaproducto.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td class="col-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ab, amet perferendis labore porro, voluptatibus vero voluptate assumenda ipsam maiores quibusdam adipisci numquam ratione consectetur omnis officiis, culpa saepe rerum.</td>
      <td class="col-1">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
              <option>6</option>
              <option>7</option>
              <option>8</option>
              <option>9</option>
              <option>10</option>
              <option>11</option>
              <option>12</option>
              <option>13</option>
              <option>14</option>
              <option>15</option>
              <option>16</option>
              <option>17</option>
              <option>18</option>
              <option>19</option>
              <option>20</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1 td-precio">60€</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Que se me está pasando ?

Comment: Agrega las hojas de estilo, hasta donde recuerdo `d-flex`, `thead-dark`, `col-2` y demás clases que veo no son parte de bootstrap. ¿No será que estás olvidando definir como `col-md-2` o `col-lg-2` o `col-sm-2` ?

Comment: @fredyfx tienes razón, no se por qué estaba así en el ejemplo, lo corregí pero aun así, la imagen que aparece en la columna, no aparece, y la columna descripción se le fatal ya que el texto aparece como en vertical al no entrar bien... No hay forma de salte a otra linea cada columna de la tabla ? o bien eliminar una columna de la tabla dependiendo si me encuentro en xs sm o md + ??

Comment: Se habrán olvidado quizás, en fin hermano, de todas maneras, dale click derecho, inspeccionar elemento usando el navegador de tu preferencia y revisa los nombres de las clases y propiedades que tienes, con eso podrás realizar mejor análisis de casos. Sí, hay varias formas, para ello agrega el código CSS que utilizas de tal manera que la comunidad puede colaborar con tu respuesta :D

Comment: Los estilos d-flex y thead-dark si son de boostrap y lo del col-2 ya está solucionado era col-md-2 pero aun así solo se reducen los espacios pero no pasan las columnas unas detras de otras.
No tengo estilos que interfieran en la tabla excepto colores en las letras de algunas columnas

Comment: ¡Madre santa x.x!, tengo que ver la nueva versión de Bootstrap que desconocía esos nombres de clases. Utiliza diversos tamaños en el mismo elemento, es decir un col-md-2, col-sm-4, col-xs-6 juntos por ejemplo

Comment: Aun así no cambia

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101248/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-rodrypaladin).

Comment: @Rodrypaladin todas las clases que menciona fredyfx en el 1er comentario existen, incluida la clase `col-2`. Adicional, las tablas son el elemento más difícil de trabajar en responsive, te recomendaría usar contenedores en flex.

Answer (score 2):

si lo que quieres es una Tabla que se adapte a todas los tamaños (responsive) deberias usar la clase de Bootstrap **table-responsive**

Tu tabla quedaria algo asi:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="productSizes" class="table">
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Es correcto, me ganaste la respuesta!

Comment: Pero el OP está usando el sistema de columnas dentro de la tabla, debes hacer hincapié en ellos en tu respuesta, de resto, la clase `table-responsive` no va a hacer nada por sí sola.